# Only make button clickable when 1/3 + 1/3 radio options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How do I make it so that the next `<button>`  on the bottom of the html is only clickable WHEN *one of each* `<input type="radio">` is checked? Also, how do I apply it with my current function?

The button itself triggers a jquery which will hide this particular fieldset and display another (see bottom of javascript).

HTML:

```
<div id="q1">
<fieldset class="fiel" name="q1">
<?php  
    $tidlol=$_GET['team'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='teamid' value='$tidlol'>";
?>
<img class="img2" src="img/q1.svg" alt="communication">
<img class="img3" src="img/f1.svg" alt="communication">
<div class="qb">
    <div class="great">
        <p class="tq"><?php echo $q1awesome ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="alone">
        <p class="tq"><?php echo $q1awful ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset class="mama">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio"   name="trend1" value="Progressing" onchange="GrabTrend(this)" />
            <img src="upp.png">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Constant" onchange="GrabTrend(this)" />
            <img src="right.png">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Regressing" onchange="GrabTrend(this)" />
            <img src="down.png">
        </label>
    </li>
</fieldset>
<div id="answ">
    <div id="forklarning">
        <p class="fq"><b>Factors to consider</b>: <?php echo $ftc1 ?></p>
    </div>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="q1r1" name="q1" value="Awesome" onchange="GrabData(this)">
        <label class="button1" for="q1r1">Awesome</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="q1r2" name="q1" value="Ok" onchange="GrabData(this)">
        <label class="button2" for="q1r2">Ok</label>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="q1r3" name="q1" value="Awful" onchange="GrabData(this)">
        <label class="button3" for="q1r3">Awful</label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="comment">
          <textarea name='q1comment' id='comment'></textarea>
    <br>

    </div>

    <div id="hideQ1" style="float:right;">
          <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ1">Next</button>   
    </div>
</div>  
</fieldset>
</div> <!--Forgot to include the first div..-->
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#hideQ1").click(function() {
            $("#q1").toggle();
            $("#q2").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

It must check for two radio checks in a particular fieldset,

```
<fieldset class="fiel" name="q1">
```

that is, since when I click "Next", this fieldset will hide and another one will appear with new radio boxes.

EDIT 2:

The next following div is identical, but +1 on numbers

```
<div id="q2" style="display:none;">
        <fieldset class="fiel" name="q2">
            <img class="img2" src="img/q2.svg" alt="communication">
            <img class="img3" src="img/f2.svg" alt="communication">
            <div class="qb">
                <div class="great">
                    <p class="tq"><?php echo $q2awesome ?></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="alone">
                    <p class="tq"><?php echo $q2awful ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="mama">

                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Progressing" onchange="GrabTrend2(this)" />
                        <img src="upp.png">
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Constant" onchange="GrabTrend2(this)" />
                        <img src="right.png">
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Regressing" onchange="GrabTrend2(this)"/>
                        <img src="down.png">
                    </label>
                </li>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="answ">
                <div id="forklarning">
                    <p class="fq"><b>Factors to Consider </b>: <?php echo $ftc2 ?></p>
                </div>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="q2r1" name="q2" value="Awesome" onchange="GrabData2(this)">
                    <label class="button1" for="q2r1">Awesome</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="q2r2" name="q2" value="Ok" onchange="GrabData2(this)">
                    <label class="button2" for="q2r2">Ok</label>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="q2r3" name="q2" value="Awful" onchange="GrabData2(this)">
                    <label class="button3" for="q2r3">Awful</label>
                </li> 
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="comment">
                    <textarea name='q2comment' id='comment'></textarea>             
                </div>

                <div id="hideQ2" style="float:right;">
                    <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ2">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

and the jQuery for 2..

```
    //Show/hide questions on click Next
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $("#hideQ1").click(function() {
                    $("#q1").toggle();
                    $("#q2").toggle();
                });
            });
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $("#hideQ2").click(function() {
                    $("#q2").toggle();
                    $("#q3").toggle();
                });
            });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzsf8ca4/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a `change` event to the descendant `input` elements and determine whether at least two radio elements are selected. Then set the `button` element's `disabled` attribute based off of this boolean.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/L16q04qa/)

```
$('fieldset button').attr('disabled', true);

$('fieldset input').on('change', function() {
  var disabled = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input:checked').length < 2;
  $(this).closest('fieldset').find('button').attr('disabled', disabled);
});
```

Comment: But problem with that is that when I click next, these two radio sections will hide, and another one will appear (hence the function on the bottom of the page), so when two are checked I will be able to click next on the rest of the questions without checking them

Comment: @MoMononoke If you provide the rest of the HTML in the example I provided, I'll show you how... without that HTML I'm not sure how you would target it.

Comment: Oh gosh alright. It's really long though, how about just one more question?

Comment: @MoMononoke Yeah, that works.. I just need to know what exactly you're toggling..

Comment: @MoMononoke See [this updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/L16q04qa/). You need to initially disabled all of the button elements. I'd suggest adding a common class to them so that you can easily select them as well..

Comment: I'll be checking it out tomorrow evening, up to work in 4 hrs. Thanks for the help (and ur patience)

Answer (score 0):

You should check for checked radio input count in last fieldset like

```
var ACTIVE = false;

$("input").change(function(){
    ACTIVE = true;
    if($("fieldset").last().children("input:radio:checked").length != 1 ) 
  {
    ACTIVE = false;
  }

  $("#submit").prop("disabled", !ACTIVE);
})
```

[Check out this edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8govjbvc/2/)

Comment: WOuldn't this mean that all radio box sections on the page must be checked for me to click next? If I click next now, two new questions with new answers will appear, so that wouldn't work for me..

Comment: yes it do mean that - I'm sorry then - I misunderstood you - check out my edit

Comment: Hmm those radio buttons of urs seem to work like checkboxes for some reason? Check my edit and see how I go to the next question

Comment: they did not have names so up - I modify it also - I'm not really sure what your problem is now

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Up to work in 4 hrs, so I gotta get some sleep. I'll check it out tomorrow evening!